# Insert cassandra column family with composite key

Tags: nosql, cassandra, composite-primary-key, hector

I have a column family `AllLog` create that

```
create column family LogData
  with column_type = 'Standard'
  and comparator = 'CompositeType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)'
  and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
  and key_validation_class = 'CompositeType(UTF8Type,UTF8Type)';
```

but when I use mutator to insert :

```
    String key0 = "key0";
    String key1 = "key1";

    Composite compositeKey = new Composite();
    compositeKey.addComponent(key0, StringSerializer.get());
    compositeKey.addComponent(key1, StringSerializer.get());

    // add
    mutator.addInsertion(compositeKey, columnFamilyName, HFactory.createColumn("name", "value"));
    mutator.execute();
```

always through exception:

```
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException:
InvalidRequestException(why:Not enough bytes to read value of component 0)
```

Please some one help me, where is my mistake in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema specifies comparator as a Composite type, yet the insertion creates a column with a single string ("name").

Comment: yes i know it but i wonder that: have any solution that i can create a table with a composite key and others column is use UTF8 type ???? i try it in cql3 is okie but in hector , i can't insert data to such table :( :(

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here... with the specified schema, you should update the code so createColumn uses a Composite name, else revise the schema to make the comparator utf8.